# android OkHttpClient Requesting Error

Tags: java, android, mysql, okhttp

I am trying to store some data in mysql database using my android app. I am using okhttp3 to send request , but an error appears to me at this line:

```
client.newCall(request).execute();
```

I tried it on local machine and online but it gives me the same error here is the code ,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String token1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        System.out.println("MainActivity is :" + FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken());
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("test");
        FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        token1=FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    }

    public void clicking(View view) {

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        RequestBody body = new FormBody.Builder()
                .add("Token",token1)
                .build();

        okhttp3.Request request = new okhttp3.Request.Builder()
                .url("http://saleh923.byethost8.com/hii.html")
                .post(body)
                .build();

        try {
            client.newCall(request).execute();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the log:

```
 com.example.user.firebasenot E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.user.firebasenot, PID: 3280
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
     Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1273)
        at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:431)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
        at okhttp3.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:39)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:172)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:138)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:80)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:178)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:129)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:98)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:109)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:124)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:170)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:60)
        at com.example.user.firebasenot.MainActivity.clicking(MainActivity.java:54)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: you should upvote and mark an answer that you think is correct. That would make more people to help you in times like this at StackOverflow. #SOBeginnerTips

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message says it all:

> Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

You are not supposed to make network requests on the main (aka UI) thread.
There are many ways in which you can make this request on a different thread, here's one:

```
final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
RequestBody body = new FormBody.Builder()
        .add("Token",token1)
        .build();

final okhttp3.Request request = new okhttp3.Request.Builder()
        .url("http://saleh923.byethost8.com/hii.html")
        .post(body)
        .build();

final Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            client.newCall(request).execute();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

But `okhttp` makes it easier for us to make asynchronous requests using the [enqueue method](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Call.html#enqueue-okhttp3.Callback-):

```
client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
        if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
            throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
        }

        // you code to handle response
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you should go about debugging your code:
Your 1st cue in the log that states,

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for
>   android:onClick

tells you that there is something wrong with you onClick method implementation, which in this case is `clicking(View view)`. You then go on to hunt for your next hint, which is your 2nd cue in the log that states,

> Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

and that certainly is happening in your `clicking(View view)` method implementation line that you pointed out. It's making a network request from the main thread; and oh!, Android system reckons it a bad thing.

So what is the way out? You can use any of the following alternatives methods:

Alternative 1: View.post(Runnable) or View.postDelayed(Runnable, long)

Alternative 2: Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable)

Alternative 3: Handler

Alternative 4: AsyncTask

I have demoed each of these alternatives, including the wrong way like the one you showcased in my Github project titled, [DemoThreadsAndProcesses](https://github.com/AndroidStuff/DemoThreadsAndProcesses). Please feel free to (fork and) download it and play with it to see which implementation alternative suits your interest and go about using it in you own very project.

For quick check, I'll go about implementing your `clicking(View view)` like below:

```
public void clicking(View view) {
   new MakeNetworkRequestAsyncTask().execute();
}

private void makeNetworkRequest() {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        RequestBody body = new FormBody.Builder()
                .add("Token",token1)
                .build();

        okhttp3.Request request = new okhttp3.Request.Builder()
                .url("http://saleh923.byethost8.com/hii.html")
                .post(body)
                .build();

        try {
            client.newCall(request).execute();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

private class MakeNetworkRequestAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
   // The system calls this to perform work in a worker thread and
   // delivers it the parameters given to AsyncTask.execute()
   protected transient Void doInBackground(Void[] params) {
      makeNetworkRequest();
   }

   // The system calls this to perform work in the UI thread and
   // delivers the result from doInBackground() method defined above
   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {}
}
```

Hope that helps!